# Change attributs in object js acording to another attribut

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm asking for an ideia. 
I have this object y that has a lot of attributs. I got this situation that I must change some y's attributs acording to a x value. But at this point, I'm writing myobj in a JSON file and reading it in other script. So, I can't use a function as an attribut. How would be your solution to "keep" all the information of " if x gets 3, then y.attt1 = 2, y.att2 = 3 ..."

```
var myobj = {
x : ,
y : {{{}}}, // this has a lot of attributs
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do exactly is not possible. Once you serialize it with `JSON.stringify(myobj)`, and deserialize it with `JSON.parse()` in another file, all getter and setter functionality is gone.

Generally speaking storing derived values is a bad idea.

Create a factory, that receives as input the serialized state object, which contains only the needed information, and returns an instance of an object with your required behavior.